# Activate button when write text in editText android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout where I have some edittexts and one button. This button is setEnabled(false). How I can change his status when user write some text in edittext? I want to when user put some text to edit text button setEnabled on true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `TextWatcher`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Its a good idea to also notify user *why* the Button is disabled.

Use a `TextWatcher` to disable/enable button and also set a error hint for EditText:

`mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new EmptyValidator());`

```
private class EmptyValidator implements TextWatcher {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (editable.length() == 0) {
                mEditText.setError("Required");
                mButton.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                mEditText.setError(null);
                mButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your code and requirement, the below code should work fine:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable string) {
        if(string.length() > 0) {
            mButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out the current length of edittext and that you get from TextWatcher
if your EditText's minimum length one(1) or not null then setEnabled(true); else default false.

check conditioned :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if(edt.getText().toString().length()<=0)
              { 
           edt.setError("Required.");
           btn.setEnable(true);
               } 

       else
         {
       btn.setEnable(true); 
         }


            }
        });
```